# Questions about using a per-function-struct (parameter object) to emulate "named arguments" for options to function calls?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

To improve code readability for options passed as arguments to a function I'm using a per-function-struct (*parameter object*) to emulate "named arguments" at the function invocation. The option values, members of the struct, typically have default values, so that at
function invocation not all options need to be specified. See the example code below for illustration.

I'm thinking of using this approach more widely for function invocations because the code seems quite compact while still readable when used with an initializer list without giving the type of the parameter object. Another advantage is that the implementation of the invoked function is straight forward/simple. However, I wonder:

1. Does this approach (pattern, idiom) have a name?
2. Can someone confirm this approach is portable? (It compiles with the
   gcc- and clang-versions I use, but is it guaranteed by the
   standard?)
3. Can someone confirm it requires C++14 and not just C++11?
4. Should I watch out for reduced execution speed or
   increase memory useage?  Or will the compilers be able to
   efficiently optimize this? Note: In my current use cases these aspects are not a
   factor, but I wonder if they might be a reason to avoid this as a
   general approach.
5. [optional] One drawback with the approach is that it requires me to create and name an extra struct,
   `SetupOptions` in the example. If I use a convention of naming the
   type of the parameter object as `<function-name>Options` I'll sometimes get
   rather long function declarations. Any suggestions for how to work
   around this? A naming convention? Or can the "named arguments" be
   emulated in a better way while still keeping the implementation
   relatively simple?
6. [optional] Do we expect a future C++1z or later to provide better approaches
   for named function parameters? (I know of [N4172](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4172.htm) but not it's status)
7. [optional] One example of a potential drawback with this approach is that the
   user might forget to change all the options. 
   Do you see other drawbacks or caveats to be careful about?

### Example code

The example below is based on an actual use case where I setup a
simulator / simulated environment.

```
/// @file Simulator.h
/// Simulator for interaction with HW devices. Used e.g. by test cases.
namespace Simulator {

struct SetupOptions {
    bool faster_than_real_time = false;
    double time_step = 0.01; // [s]
};

void setup(SetupOptions options) {
    if (options.faster_than_real_time) {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
} // namespace Simulator

/// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
/// @file use_simulator.cpp

void setup_simulator_for_application() {
    Simulator::setup({}); // (1) Uses default setup
    // ...
}

void setup_simulator_for_test_case() {
    // (2) Use named struct member for readability
    Simulator::setup({.faster_than_real_time = true});
    // ..
}
```

### Some relevant links:

- https://marcoarena.wordpress.com/2014/12/16/bring-named-parameters-in-modern-cpp/ - the approach discussied in this SO question *might* correspond to a subset of the "Named Parameter Idiom" in the link.
- [N4172](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4172.htm) - Proposal for named arguments.

Comment: You also have the [Boost parameter library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/parameter/doc/html/index.html). It's a little harder to use, but should be very flexible.

Comment: Thanks, the Boost parameter library was discussed in Marco Arena's blog post. Unfortunately the use seem to be a bit complicated for my taste, but it certainly seem powerful.
I'm probably ok with the approach I used... would like a name for it though, or confirm it's called using a *parameter object* to pass the arguments.

Comment: Btw, I tested the example and -std=c++11 was not enough for clang v3.6, but it works with -std=c++14. It also didn't work with g++ v4.9.3 and -std=c++14 or c++1y.  (I was actually burnt by this today when compiling on a different machine). So for question 2, C++14 does seem to be required.

Comment: One question per question, please. Not _seven_!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone confirm it requires C++14 and not just C++11?

None of them. It requires C99/C11 designated initializers. Which are *not part* of any version of C++.

So what you're writing isn't standard C++ at all. It's based on compilers permitting C11 code in C++.

> Do we expect a future C++1z or later to provide better approaches for named function parameters?

The closest you're likely to get in the forseeable future is for something like [this paper (PDF)](http://wg21.link/P0329) to get standardized in C++20. That provides C++ support for designated initializers, but even then, it won't be compatible with C99/11's designated initializers.

So if you continue with this hybrid C11/C++11 syntax, it may become illegal.

Comment: Thanks for the linked paper. The code I used seem to fall within that proposal, so I hope it eventually makes it in. Until then I'll stay away from this "pattern" even though it compiles without warnings with clang and gcc on Linux/Mac/Win.
I'll post a separate question to ask if there was a way the compiler or similar could've told me the code wasn't standard compliant.

Comment: Not sure it's worth a question of it's own to ask how to detect it. 
Adding the option '-pedantic' to gcc warns:
    warning: ISO C++ does not allow C99 designated initializers [-Wpedantic]

Comment: @chr: You could just use `-pedantic`, which makes those "warnings" into errors.